# Show the AlertDialog once by using flag

Tags: java, android

I am sending data route,long, lat, mac to the Server very 10 seconds. Often the route is 0. In this case, the server will be asked for the route. As soon as the app has the route from the server , Checkbox `AlertDialog` appears to confirm the result by the user. Then the route will be envloped with the other data Long, lat, mac as `JSOn` string and transmitted to the server again.

I am facing Problem that the alert Dialogs will pile up when the user does not interact with the Dialog immediatly. What I am trying to achieve is to pop up the Dialog window just once when the server provides the app with route and not very 10 seconds with the Response from the server since when the user reacts too late he has to confirm all these Dialog Windows also after 1 Minute he has to confirm 6 Dialog Windows. Therefor, I am using `flag` to reach that but the problem currently with flag is when it is set once to false it is not possiable to enter the `stop_popup` method again till the app is restarted gain.

Is there anyway to set the `flag` variable to true after 10 minutes without interupting sending the data to the server?

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback  {

    boolean flag = true;
      ......
        @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskFinished(ArrayList<Integer> routeList, double distance) {
        if (distance <= 15 && speed <= 4 && flag== true) {
            popup_dialog(routeList);

        } else {
            route_number = routeList.get(0);
            System.out.println("The route number is: " + route_number);
        }

    }


    private void popup_dialog(final ArrayList<Integer> routeList) {


        int routeListSize = routeList.size();
        flag = false;

        if (routeListSize > 0) {
      //AlertDialog.Build code
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a postDelayed `Handler` that turns  `flag = true` after 10 minutes.

```
private void popup_dialog(final ArrayList<Integer> routeList) {
    int routeListSize = routeList.size();

    flag = false;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            flag =true;                       
        }
    }, 10 * 1000 * 60);  // 10 minutes (60 sec * 1000 milliseconds)

    if (routeListSize > 0) {
        //AlertDialog.Build code
}
```

Comment: Where do I have to set it in the `onAsyncTaskFinished()` or `popup_dialog()`  method or somewhere else? does not this approach interupt the connection with the server for 10 minutes?

Comment: nope, it wont stop server, will run in a separated thread, check my edit... hope it clarifies...